# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel error when both client and server support TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, .net

We have upgraded our server to only accept TLS 1.2 and disabled SHA/MD5. Now from this server, we are calling a third party API that supports TLS 1.2, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0. Now, whenever I call this third part api using C# HttpClient library I am getting `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel error`. From code I set,

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

I am getting the same error. The only way to get rid of this error is to enable TLS 1.2, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0 in my server. How can I enable only TLS 1.2 while making my third party api work or how can I get more information what is the main cause of TLS error?

Comment: @anx I am noob, let's say api domain is abc.com then how can I test whether the api domain is negotiating TLS1_2 successfully?

Comment: It shows `Protocol  : TLSv1.2  Cipher    : RC4-MD5` what does this means?

Comment: @user960567: it means that the server uses a cipher with MD5 - exactly what you've explicitly disabled in your client.

Comment: Thanks anx. Excallant information. I have found very helpfull tool

Comment: Yes @SteffenUllrich you are 100% correct. I have checked with https://www.ssllabs.com/ what is negotiated with a different browser information